# How to use webrtc in a mobile app using node.js and express api?

Tags: android, node.js, express, flutter, webrtc

I have read an article about live video streaming apps and how to build them.

In the article, there were solutions for adding this feature.

One of them was WebRTC, My question is can I use it in an android app using node.js with express API?

if yes, how to do this in the best way?

I am a flutter developer.

Thanks,